# TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Tags: python, django

I saw this question elsewhere, but the answer is not applicable. I am following a course, copying the exact code, yet it doesn't work. Please tell me of any errors.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    return render('post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    })


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

This is my exact code, please tell me what I did wrong. I am also new to Django.

Comment: This looks like your error is somewhere in files that you did not share here. Review your Django log and inspect where exactly it happens.

Comment: I also got this error:
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '

Comment: This is my urls.py file:
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'post/(.*)$', blog_views.post),
    url(r'^about/$', blog_views.about),
    url(r'^$', blog_views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: The dictionary goes into template. You probably do not iterate properly over values in **about.html** or **index.html**. Carefully review the log in the browser to identify where this happens.

Comment: By the way, you are missing `request` argument in `post` view in `render` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "post" view is missing the request in the render method and should be:

```
def post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    return render(
        request, 
        'post.html', 
        {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)}
    )
```